# Login fails from Windows on NTFS-3G Samba Share

Tags: debian, samba, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have a Raspberry Pi (though could be any Debian Linux box) connected to an external hard disk formatted as NTFS.

My disk mount in `fstab` is:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/disk  ntfs-3g  defaults,uid=1000,gid-1000,dmask=007,fmask=007  0  0
```

where user 1000 is the 'pi' user

/media/disk/shared is my Samba root folder. Must be accessible from Windows and Mac

Now, I can see the share in Windows, but I get permission denied. If I try mapping a drive to it, and attempt login using \machinename\pi the login fails.

Any ideas?

Edit-- smb.conf below. I've removed all comment lines (I assume lines beginning # or ; are comments)

```
[global]

   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

   usershare allow guests = yes

[shared]
   comment = Ali and Greg Shared Folders
   writeable = yes
   public = yes
   browseable = yes
   path = /media/disk/shared
   guest only = yes
   guest ok = yes

   read only = no

   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[hdd]
   comment = Samba server's HDD
   read only = no
   locking = no
   path = /media/disk/shared
   guest ok = yes
```

Comment: Did you add the users to the Samba password database using `smbpasswd -a`?  Samba does not authenticate against `/etc/shadow` && `/etc/passwd`.  See `http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbpasswd.8.html`.

Comment: More confused! I tried smbpasswd. Still couldn't connect. Created a new share. Still couldn't connect. Messed with various Windows (8) file sharing and network discovery settings. It starts working on the new share (but not the old one). I then one by one change all the Windows settings back to what they were, expecting the share to stop working... it still works. I will try to redo this server from scratch from my notes and figure this out. But not tonight! Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: In smb.conf, the share that works is /media/disk, the share that doesn't is /media/disk/shared. Both have the same permissions.

Comment: Attempting to connect from a second Windows 7 PC failed. I go back to the partially working Windows 8 PC, and now that fails to connect on both shares. I have changed nothing on the Debian box. This is too random. I am beyond help. Will start from scratch :(

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your `smb.conf` file?

Comment: I've added smb.conf

Comment: I happen to have an rpi myself.  I'm setting up samba on it now.  when it's working, I'll post the config and steps I took.

Comment: One final comment.  I'm 100% sure that `ntfs-3g` has nothing to do with the permissions issues you're seeing.  If user accounts can write to the drive when locally attached, you're fine for samba.

Comment: I think some of the seemingly random behaviour is due to windows 'remembering' credentials for shares, even after I've changed the share settings in Samba. During the experimenting phase, I found it much more reliable to use the windows command line "net use z: \\server\share /user:username"  and "net use Z: /delete". Don't use Explorer until everthing is finalised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my configuration and it works:

```
[public]
comment = Public Storage
path = /media/hddusb
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0771
read only = no
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
```

Comment: This works for me, provided my fstab mount point is set up with no security at all (mask permissions of 000). I had to work that bit out for myself :)

Comment: I commented on my own post below before I read this.  I'm glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

From 0 to Samba on RaspberryPi (Debian)!

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/log# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.1.9+ #272 PREEMPT Tue Aug 7 22:51:44 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux
root@raspberrypi:/var/log# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux wheezy/sid \n \l
```

This works for me on my Pi.  The `smb.conf` is 8 lines (not counting the blank).  I've connected with both Mac OSX and Windows 7 clients without issue using the username `testme` with password set to `testme`.  ***You could literally paste this line for line other than setting the passwords.***

```
##the REQUIRED smbpasswd is part of samba-common-bin -- YOU MUST EXPLICITY SELECT IT
aptitude install samba samba-common-bin
mkdir -p /data/share
chmod 1777 /data/share
cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.bak

cat > /etc/samba/smb.conf << "EOF"
workgroup = workgroup
netbios name = rpi
encrypt passwords = yes

[share]
path = /data/share
read only = no
browseable = yes
valid users = testme
EOF

useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/testme -m testme
passwd testme ##set password
smbpasswd -a testme ##set same password; this is used for samba authentication

/etc/init.d/samba restart

### DONE!! ###
```

Comment: Tried that. I can still see the share in Windows, but cannot open it. How is the testme user granted access to the mounted folder which has owner 'pi'? From what I can tell, the masks in my fstab only allow owner and group access to the disk.

Comment: I would remove `/etc/fstab` from the equation, and even `NTFS` for the moment.  Mount a local directory as a samba share.  If that works, mount the `NTFS` share with a simple mount command which, devoid of `fstab`, accepts the default options.  I plugged in a `NTFS` formatted disk, mounted it with `mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs` and then shared it out with samba without issue.

Comment: Now I've changed to using 'permissions' instead of 'defaults' in my fstab mount, your method using smbpasswd works perfectly. Thanks